# How do you convert binary to decimal if the binary was 1.01?

Tags: binary

What is 1.01 binary in decimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remember we use positional numbering system.

```
1101 = 2^0 + 2^2 + 2^3  =  1 + 4 + 8  =  13
1.01 = 2^0 + 2^(-2)     =  1 + 1/4    =  1.25
```

Answer (score 2):

Positions to the *left* of the unit *multiply* by 2 each time. Positions to the *right* of the unit **divide** by 2 each time.

```
1 .   0       1
1×1 + 0×1/2 + 1×1/4 = 1 1/4
```

Comment: I wish my maths teachers at school had shown me this - I might have become a C developer

Answer (score 1):

It's 1.25:

```
  1 * 2^0 + 0 * 2^-1 + 1 * 2^-2
= 1 * 1   + 0 * 0.5  + 1 * 0.25
= 1                  + 0.25
= 1.25
```